# Share monitors/keyboard/mouse between laptop and desktop

Tags: windows-10, laptop, multiple-monitors, kvm-switch, screen-sharing

I have a work **laptop** (with WiFi) and a home **desktop** PC (with LAN + WiFi) - both Windows 10.

I would like to **share** my desktop **monitors/keyboard/mouse** with the laptop, preferably being able to **switch** between laptop and desktop **quickly**.

My attempts:

- *Remote Desktop* is the obvious solution, but it is disabled on my laptop :(
- *Windows 10 Miracast* can only extend to one monitor and the mouse is laggy. (Also switching from desktop back to the laptop is problematic, as when you click on nothing it often closes a window because the mouse position is different)

Anyone know better options? I prefer software solution but it might be blocked, so I'm open to hardware solutions too.

(Googling this I found new terms: docking station, KVM, USB switch - I'm not familiar with any of them and not sure if/how they could help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the solution
https://youtu.be/pwfAAn9e1jE

What to buy:

- [Plugable USB 3.0 Universal Laptop Docking Station UD3900](https://www.amazon.com.au/dp/B07XJ7QN7Q) (AUD 130)
- [Plugable USB 3.0 Sharing Switch](https://www.amazon.com.au/Plugable-Sharing-One-Button-Swapping-Computers/dp/B00JX3Q28Y/) (AUD 25)

Answer (score 0):

A kvm allows you to switch between which device your peripherals are connected to. It would mean that the keyboard mouse and monitor would all effect only one of the devices and could be switched between them at will (with the press of a button). A dock allows you to quickly connect multiple peripherals to a device (normally a laptop) it wouldn’t effect your desktop, so probably not ideal and I haven’t heard of a USB switch before. Personally I would do a kvm of those three options but I don’t really know.